# How to put items to JoinableQueue before calling task_done?

Tags: python, gevent, python-multithreading

I create a JoinableQueue instance and add a few items to it. Then create consumer workers to consume these items in Queue.

However the problem is I need to be able to add new items to the queue in these workers but when task_done() is not called after q.get() Gevent doesn't allow me to this operation. If I add newItems to the queue after calling task_done(), I can't be sure all items are consumed.

It throws `gevent.hub.LoopExit: This operation would block forever`

```
q = JoinableQueue()

def worker():
    item = q.get()
    newItems = consumeItem(item)
    [q.put(newItem) for newItem in newItems]
    q.task_done()

for item in initialItems:
    q.put(item)

for i in range(10):
    gevent.spawn(worker)

q.join() # I have to be sure all items are consumed when join stops blocking the program.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: use two queues: a `JoinableQueue` for incoming jobs, and another queue for the output. Currently jobs are `put` into the queue, then `task_done` is called for each, but not for the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your workers are running just once. If your queue has more items than your spawned workers, it never finishes.

Solution is simple, just add a loop to workers:

```
def worker():
    for item in iter(q.get, None):
        newItems = consumeItem(item)
        [q.put(newItem) for newItem in newItems]
        q.task_done()
```

Now all of them keep working until the queue is empty.

Comment: Note that `empty()` is not reliable according to the documentation of the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: @LaryxDecidua I am not sure if the gevent version of this queue has that limitation since it is not a multithreaded implementation. Still, I modified the code to replace it.